# How to move an image automatically throughout the screen each second using flutter?

Tags: flutter

This is my UI
[image]

I want to move this man to the pond little by little, every movement should be in every second.

here is the my code

```
class _QuestionScreenState extends State<QuestionScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(Config.app_SelectionPageBackground1),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 700.0,top: 200),
                    child: Image.asset(Config.app_man),
                  )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when the man went to the pond then should stop moving.. How to do that using flutter?

Comment: check https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/animations/tutorial and https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/animations in general

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable which holds the current second:

```
int seconds = 0;
```

We can move the image on the screen with AnimatedPosition, Transform.translate, etc. Find the widget you need, i'll use Transform.translate for this. Wrap your image inside a Transform.translate:

```
Transform.translate(
  offset: Offset(seconds * 10,0),
  child: yourImage,
)
```

You have to provide a Offset. The first value in the Offset constructor is the x coordinate, so every second we move more to the right (10,20,30). You can change the 10.0, just a random number which i used here.

To move the character every second you can use a Timer.

Start the timer with this function:

```
void startTimer() {
 
   Timer.periodic(
     Duration(seconds: 1),
    (Timer timer) {
       setState(() {
          seconds = seconds + 1;
        });
    },
  );
}
```

Call the function to start the movement of the character.